# Recursive function for DOM to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dom

I'm trying to create a JSON index of a particular section of HTML. Here is the HTML that I have:

```
<div class="box span12">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="item span12" data-width-helper="12"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="box span6">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="item span12" id="4" data-width-helper="12"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="box span6">
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="item span12" id="6" data-width-helper="12"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="item span12" id="7" data-width-helper="12"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item span6" id="5" data-width-helper="6"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item span6" data-width-helper="6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="item span8" id="2" data-width-helper="8"></div>
        <div class="item span4" id="3" data-width-helper="4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ultimately, I'd like to end up with JSON that looks like this:

```
[
    [
        {
            "id":1,
            "width":12
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "width":6,
            "items":
            [
                [
                    {
                        "id":4,
                        "width":12
                    }
                ],
                [
                    {
                        "width":6,
                        "items":
                        [
                            [
                                {
                                    "id":6,
                                    "width":12
                                }
                            ],
                            [
                                {
                                    "id":7,
                                    "width":12
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id":5,
                        "width":6
                    }
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "id":8,
            "width":6
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id":2,
            "width":8
        },
        {
            "id":3,
            "width":4
        }
    ]
]
```

So basically, each box holds an array of rows, which holds an array of items, which are objects with a little descriptive information.  I can't seem to wrap my head around a recursive function that will build out that json object so that there can be `box`es instead of `item`s going down unlimited levels.

Hopefully someone smarter than me can take the time to help out - I'd really appreciate it. And as a side note, I'm fine with using jQuery and/or Underscore.js

Comment: Have you done something?

Comment: How is the function supposed to work? What should it do when you come across a `box` vs a `row-fluid` vs an `item`? And like Sam said... What have you done so far?

Comment: You're missing ids on the items #1 and #8. And please show us what you've tried, the recursive function isn't that complicated. What's your problem on treating item- and box-divs differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how you want the function to work, so I just wrote a bit of psuedocode for you. The goal here was to make every tag into an array of its children, unless the tag was an item, in which case, it creates an object with "width" and "id" instead.

```
function toJSON(element)
    var returnObject;
    switch
        case: item
            returnObject = {
                "id": elementId,
                "width": elementWidth
            };
            break;
        case: default
            returnObject = [];
            for each child
                returnObject.push(toJSON(child));
            break;
    return returnObject;
```

Comment: YES! Not sure why I couldn't come up with that myself, but that worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!